# QField App crashes when connect to internal server of PostgreSQL and PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, qfield

I'm completely new to GIS field and here what I'm trying to do:

I want to make the QField App connects to internal server which has a PostgreSQL and PostGIS running on it.

1. I created a schema in PostgreSQL with one geometry type.
2. I enabled the PostGIS to the database
3. I created a QGIS project, and added the OpenStreetMap as a layer.
4. I also used Add layer and chose PostGIS and select my schema (from PostgreSQL)
5. Also, tried to export the project with QfieldSync

Also, I changed the IPv4 in `pg_hba.conf` and set firewall rules for PostgreSQL port(5432).

When I use QGis to select points, everything works fine and all data stored to my database. However, when I copy the project to my android phone and use QField, it crashes once I select the project without showing any error.

Is there a special way to export the project to fit with QField?

If I use shapeFiles as layer, the QField works just fine and store data locally but it is not what I need.

Comment: It says that ssl support for PostGIS is not yet enabled [here](https://qfield.org/docs/project-management/dataformat.html).  You would have to disable ssl, so maybe you'll have to create an intermediate layer that you can script to copy to your postgis on a regular interval.

Comment: Thank you, I already solve it after a day of struggling. I will post it

Answer (score 2):

After a day of struggling, I found part of the solution [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/error-connecting-to-database-fatal-no-pg_hba-conf-entry-for-host-x-x-x-x-user-jiradbuser-database-jiradb-ssl-off-950801726.html)

which is basically just altering the **pg_hba.conf** file and adding server IP with /24

The other part was removing the password from the configuration of the project and just checking the Store option